# maven-dependency-plugin:generate-resources:unpack-dependencies - strip file's qualified name to absolute name

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

maven-dependency-plugin,

phase : generate-resources

goal : unpack-dependencies

I want all resolved files with absolute name instead of qualified name.

Any help please?

Comment: What do you mean by absolute name and qualified name?

Comment: qualified name refer here full name - e.g. /com/abc/Message.properties.  absolute name refers to : Message.properties only.